# What is the time complexity of the following code?

Tags: java, time, complexity-theory

```
/*
 * Program to group anagrams from the string array input
 */

import java.util.*;

public class StringArrayAnagrams {

    //function to group the anagrams together
    public static void groupAnagrams(String[] inputArray) { 
        Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>> store = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>>(); //to store the sorted string as keys and words from input array that have same sort string
        if (inputArray.length == 0) { 
            System.out.println("Input array is empty");
            return;
        } else if(inputArray.length == 1) { 
            System.out.println(inputArray[0]);
            return;
        }

        for(String word:inputArray) { 
            char[] temp = word.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(temp);
            String tempStr = new String(temp);
            if (store.containsKey(tempStr)) { 
                ArrayList<String> lStore = store.get(tempStr);
                lStore.add(word);
            } else { 
                ArrayList<String> newLStore = new ArrayList<String>();
                newLStore.add(word);
                store.put(tempStr,  newLStore);
            }
        }
        //to print the grouped anagrams
        Set<String> keySet = store.keySet();
        for(String eachKey:keySet) { 
            ArrayList<String> anagramList = store.get(eachKey); 
            System.out.println(anagramList);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String[] input = {"bat", "bta", "cat", "tca", "vish"}; 
        StringArrayAnagrams.groupAnagrams(input);   
    }
}
```

I wrote this code to group the anagrams together from an input string array and print them. I am still trying to learn how to answer the time complexity of the code. What would be the time complexity of the code?

Comment: What is the function supposed to do, group all words which an anagram of each other together?

Comment: Yes. Here is my output  [cat, tca]
[vish]
[bat, bta]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of processing is easier in Java 8.

```
String[] input = {"bat", "bta", "cat", "tca", "vish"}; 
Collection<List<String>> grouped = Stream.of(input)
          .collect(Collectors.groupBy(w -> sortLetters(w))
          .values();

public static String sortLetters(String w) {
    char[] letters = w.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(letters);
    return new String(letters);
}
```

The time complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of words, assuming all the words are about the same length or a small upper bound.  If the words are really long this is O(N * log N) where `N` is the length of the words.

Comment: What would be time complexity of my code ? As far I understand it should be O(m*nlogn+n). Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @user1534214 if the assume the words are reasonably short, but the number of words could be large then it is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of words.